# Determine Spring Version at runtime

Tags: spring

Is there a way to determine my Spring Version at runtime?  eg

```
log.info("I'm running spring version '{}'", SpringWhatever.getVersion());
```

Debug-level logging is not showing me anything.

Full background is that I can compile but am getting `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer.getAppliedPropertySources()` at runtime.

Comment: Your actually question is how to see what jar versions are used. Using maven use `mvn dependency:tree` to check all the jar versions. When you get `NoSuchMethodError`s or `ClassNotFoundException`s you generally are mixing jars of different versions of a framework (in this case Spring). Never mix different version as that will lead to hard to debug issues.

Comment: This was the solution to a problem I had for a long time.  I was always getting NoSuchMethodError exception with spring all the time.  This finally allowed me to solve it.  Once I found what the bad version of spring was, I found which dependency was injecting it in eclipse.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, its

```
org.springframework.core.SpringVersion.getVersion()
```

Answer (score 2):

Please note that there may be couple of versions related to Spring ecosystem, like:

- Spring Framework version (covered by answer by Roy in 2015)
- Spring Boot version - similar: `SpringBootVersion.getVersion()`
- Spring Cloud release train - ?